# If i remove hdd with Ubuntu from one notebook and plug in it to another, will it be fully functional?

Tags: hard-drive

I removed it from `Dell Inspiron 1501` and connected to `Acer Aspire 5100` via sata-usb cable and it work normal.
I am not experienced user, so I'm runned no tests on it.

Now I want to buy `Toshiba SATELLITE L850D-BJS` and reconnect my hdd to it.
Will it work and what can happen?

Comment: Remove the proprietary drivers if you have any.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes it will. Possibly it will function without a problem. Why ?

Because Ubuntu(Linux) has the most of the drivers (if not all of them) integrated.

You cannot do the same thing with Windows OS. Why ?

Because Windows OS has not the drivers integrated.When you install Windows for the first time at the first (or second maybe) update it will install automatically all the necessary drivers for your system. So if you load the specific OS to another system drivers will conflict with the different hardware.

In Ubuntu(Linux) during boot the Linux kernel searches and loads the appropriate drivers.As I said before , the drivers are integrated to the kernel.

If you have any proprietary (additional) drivers installed it will be good to remove them before make the switch. I upvoted the  Rinzwind's comment and edited my answer to add this info.

So, go for it.

Comment: +1 for the good information. I wasn't aware of that. Thank you.